# How to store reactions into quick.db

Tags: bots, discord.js, quick.db

So I want to store user reactions into quick.db

```
    let wembed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setAuthor("Armagedon RolePlay | Verify System")
    .setColor("PURPLE")
    .setThumbnail(message.author.displayAvatarURL())
    .setDescription(arg1) 

    const reactmessage = await client.channels.cache.get(chx).send(wembed)
    await reactmessage.react('✅');

    const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '✅' && !user.bot;
    const collector = reactmessage.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });

    collector.on('collect', async reaction => {      
        const user = reaction.users.cache.last();
        const guild = reaction.message.guild;
        const member = guild.member(user) || await guild.fetchMember(user);
        member.roles.add("725747028323205170");
    });
```

Basically I want to store user's reaction then store it into quick.db in case bot crashes and reboots after on users can still react to `wembed`

Answer (score 0):

Storing into quick.db or any database isn't the best idea. If you want to get working with reactions after the bot crashed/reboot, use [Client's options](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ClientOptions) where it includes partials. I recommend use this code:

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
   partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION', "GUILD_MEMBER"]
})
```

Comment: Ye but still, if I reboot the bot users can still react to the message but won't get the role

Comment: make sure you need to fetch a Member class like this `const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id)` and then add it a role.

Comment: Hmm ye but is there a way of doing this in my command file not index.js